# RFID tag, Android Format

Tags: c#, android, nfc, rfid

I am writing C# application for reading/writing RFID tags which are formatted by android aplication (NXP). I found default keys (A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5   and   D3 F7 D3 F7 D3 F7) and i can read all data from tag, but problem is that i cant write anything on it

other weird thing is that Key block looks like this 
[00 00 00 00 00 00 78 77 88 C1 00 00 00 00 00 00] and this block is authenticating by key [A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5]

My question is how authenticate sector to have permissions for writing?

Answer (score 0):

let me understand the problem - you wrote the NDEF/RTD information (URI or other) using the Android phone with NFC to some NFC tag (which one - MIFARE Ultralight, Topaz or other?). Now you have an USB NFC reader (which one?) connected to the desktop PC and you are trying to read data from tag? Is it correct?

Please confirm and put there missing information.

BR
STeN

Comment: I have 1k NFC tag which is formatted by android application, I wrote C# Winforms application  which uses NFC reader to read data from this tag, I used Keys A=(A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5) for sector 0 and A=(D3 F7 D3 F7 D3 F7) for other sector.  then I found that key B=(FFFFFFFFFFFF) gives me permission to write some data on this tag. so I can write some data using my application and android can read it.   but now there is another problem, I cant change key block. so my question is, is it possible to unformat (change keys) android formatted tag?  and what this access modifiers mean [78 77 88 C1]?